# jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.createBlob java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: jdbc, jtds

mvn:net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.3.1-patch-20190523/jar
to save to a Microsoft SQL Server database.
Actually this JDBC driver is provided by Talend. For various reasons, I have some Java JDBC code which saves blobs to the database. This works fine with an Oracle DB.

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(this.connectionString, this.user, this.pw)) {

        insert(con, ags, snr, productVersion, nummer, inhalt, this.migrationsBenutzer, format, daten);
}

public long insert(Connection con,  String ags, String snr, int productVersion ,int nummer,String inhalt, String benutzer, String format, byte[] daten) throws SQLException {
    long result = 0;
    String timestamp = now();
    try {
        Blob blob = con.createBlob();
        blob.setBytes(1, daten);
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(this.insert);
        ...
        ps.setBlob(9, blob);
        result = ps.executeUpdate();
```

However when I call the method with a connection string for jtds:
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://:1433;databaseName=

I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.createBlob(JtdsConnection.java:2776)
    at de.iteos.dao.BildspeichernDAO.insert(BildspeichernDAO.java:60)
```

What can I do? If feasible I want to keep the method a generic as possible. Do I have to switch to another JDBC driver? I have read somewhere that this could be solved with a validation query. For this I would have to implement two different DataSources for Oracle and SQL Server right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that jTDS is - as far as I know - no longer maintained, and available versions are stuck on JDBC 3.0 (Java 1.4) support. The method [`Connection.createBlob`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#createBlob()) you're trying to call was introduced in JDBC 4.0 (Java 6). Attempts to call this method on a driver that was compiled against the JDBC 3.0 API will result in `AbstractMethodError` as the method from JDBC 4.0 (or higher) is not implemented.

The simplest and best solution is probably to switch to the [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc).

Alternatively, you need to switch to the JDBC 3.0 options for populating a blob, that is, using the [`PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(int, InputStream, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream(int,java.io.InputStream,int)) method (not to be confused with [`setBinaryStream(int, InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream(int,java.io.InputStream)) or [`setBinaryStream(int, InputStream, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream(int,java.io.InputStream,long)) introduced in JDBC 4.0!), or possibly [`setBytes(int, byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBytes(int,byte%5B%5D)), or using driver specific methods for creating blobs.

The validation query solution you mention doesn't apply here, that solves a problem with [`Connection.isValid`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)) that the data source implementation in some Tomcat versions calls by default, unless you configure a validation query. It has the same underlying cause (the `isValid` method was also introduced in JDBC 4.0).

I'm not sure what you mean with *"I would have to implement two different DataSources for Oracle and SQL Server right?"*, you cannot use one and the same data source for two different databases, so you would need to configure two different instances anyway.

Comment: Great. It works now both with Oracle and MSSQL / JTDS Many thanks!!!!!