# Java jDTS setNString() throws an AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I'm trying to insert Unicode characters using Java, to a SQL Server 2016 database. Currently, I'm experiencing an issue with the `Statement.setNString(unicodeData)` method, when using the jTDS Type 4 JDBC Driver. The method throws an `AbstractMethodError`.

The normal `Statement.setString(unicodeData)` method works fine, but it inserts Unicode characters as question marks in the db. I changed to a SQL Server driver and the `Statement.setNString(unicodeData)` inserts Unicode characters with no issues, but the customer cannot change drivers like I did.
Any ideas or reasons why this happens or any way to fix this?

Comment: It does it because every `setNString` method in jTDS does this: `public void setNString(String parameterName, String value) throws SQLException { throw new AbstractMethodError(); }`. Your customer is using a driver that hasn't seen any source code updates since 2016 and isn't likely to see any updates ever again. The way to fix it is to encourage your customer to upgrade to a modern, supported driver.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.createBlob java.lang.AbstractMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69346461/jtds-jdbc-jtdsconnection-createblob-java-lang-abstractmethoderror). TL;DR: jTDS doesn't implement JDBC 4 (Java 6) support, so it doesn't have methods like `setNString`, which results in the `AbstractMethodError` at runtime.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.